# Best way to extract data from a string

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am looking for the most efficient and clean way to extract data from a string and organize it into an array of information. I'm building a tool which converts pasted memo information into a more readable format.

At the moment we receive memos for new employees like this:

> NAME:       JOHN SMITH
>
> SERVICE:      ICT
>
> MANAGER:                           JOHN TURNER
>
> POST TITLE:       IT Support Officer

I want to be able to put all of this information into an array fetched from a textarea POST and then display it on the page in a nicer format like below:

> Full Name:          John Smith
>
> Service Area:     ICT
>
> Line Manager:                        John Turner
>
> Job Title:        IT Support Officer

I am aware that I could use functions like **explode()** but I just wanted to see if there are any better ways to do this?

I want to store all of the information in an array so that it is easy to ECHO onto my webpage once it has been posted to the server.

```
$Newemployee['Name'] = "John Smith";
$Newemployee['Service'] = "ICT";
$Newemployee['Manager'] = "John Turner";
$Newemployee['Post_title'] = "IT Support Officer";
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Nope, there is no better way. Share with us what you're doing and we may be able to help you with some improvements.

Comment: you'd be better of inputting this data in text boxes rather all the information in a text area from the start for easier handling later on.

Comment: Since you are aware that you could use `explode()` for this, can you show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no control over the format of the input, and without sanitising the input in any way, I believe the most suitable way for achieving this is using the functions like **explode()** as you have described:

```
$newuser = [];

$input = "NAME: JOHN SMITH

SERVICE: ICT

MANAGER: JOHN TURNER

POST TITLE: IT Support Officer";

$lines = array_filter(explode("\n", $input));

foreach ($lines as $line) {

    $parts = explode(": ", $line);
    $newuser[ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace(" ", "_", $parts[0])))] = $parts[1];

}
```

**EDIT**

Have changed the array indexes to reflect the formatting you have described.

As for the actual values, you are usually better off storing all of the values in the same form (i.e. lowercase) and formatting them accordingly when printing them on screen. This allows you to easily compare the values without needing to know the format of each string - meaning you can detect things like the 'ICT' acronym and have it be all uppercase, whereas another 'Service' may not be an acronym and so you would prefer it to just be capitalised.

Comment: Are you sure? I have a PHPFiddle with the output: `Array ( [NAME] => JOHN SMITH [SERVICE] => ICT [MANAGER] => JOHN TURNER [POST TITLE] => IT Support Officer )`

Comment: The question asks for the 'best way to extract data from a string' - I have answered that with a suitable solution. How you then manipulate the data (for example capitalisation) is a different question